# Modify view property based on scroll amount

Tags: android

I would like to find out how to change certain properties of a view based on how far the user has scrolled down content inside a `ScrollView`. As an example, the way the action bar changes transparency in the new version of Play Music (in the album view). In that example, the action bar is completely transparent when the album art is fully visible and becomes fully opaque when the user scrolls past the album art entirely.

I understand the logic behind it, but I cannot find out what is used to calculate the transparency value of the action bar. Is it the amount the user has scrolled down, is it based on the percentage of the album art that is visible? I'm looking for one way this can be done and perhaps a link to some documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScrollView`s are annoying in that someone forgot to add the `OnScrollListener`. You have to extend them and override the `onScrollChanged` method to get notified.

Once you've done that, it's just a bit of math - I think in Play Music's case, they just time it so that it hits 100% right when the buttons underneath the album art go under it. That is, the distance you animate over is `height(album art) + height(buttons)`.